# How fade out a page after 10 seconds

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#splash").fadeOut('6000');
    $.mobile.changePage("index.html");
});
```

I am new to jQuery and want to fade out the page with ID splash after it displays for about 5 seconds and then redirect it to the index page.

My problem is that the splash screen doesn't seem to stay on for more than a second even though I have specified the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another page in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

As you've written it your second line won't wait for the first to finish. You can accomplish this with a callback:

```
$("#splash").fadeOut('6000', function(){
    $.mobile.changePage("index.html");
});
```

This executes `$.mobile.changePage("index.html");` when the fadeOut finishes.